# Facebook GET /picture is Unavailable in this version error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, deprecated, facebook-apps

I am getting developer alerts for Facebook api `GET /picture is Unavailable in this version error` from last week.

[image]

Still not able to understand what does it mean?
There are not many details of what's failing or from which platform it's affecting. I have many platforms(android, kindle, iOS, facebook) for the app.

I checked `GET /picture` is working good for facebook API for current platforms. Where it could be failing?

Is `GET /picture` deprecated for any version?
Anyone is getting this type of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_changes:

> **Picture Error** - For the Link, Post, Thread, Comment, Status, and AppRequest nodes, and other nodes which don't have a picture, the `/v2.3/{object}/picture` edge now returns an error message. Before, the API returned a placeholder image of a 'question mark' for the picture edge requested on these nodes.

Sounds like you are requesting `/picture` on a node type that doesn’t *have* this edge.